# how sort a large map by value in scala?

Tags: scala

how sort a map with 2 millions entry by value? the following method is too slow, the code can't finished in one hour on my laptop with CPU 8250U.

```
val sortedMap  = ListMap(wordCount.toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2): _*)
```

does any par collection can help or other sort mehtod?

Comment: The real killer might be `ListMap`. From the [ScalaDocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap$.html): "Note that each element insertion takes O(n) time, which means that creating a list map with n elements will take O(n^2) time. This makes the builder suitable only for a small number of elements. "

Comment: thanks a lot, your are right. now it only take 10 seconds in `val wordsFreq = finalWf.toList.sortWith(_._2 > _._2)`

Comment: I've seen breakOut being used and improving performance of collections transformations: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html